# Powershell: Sorting/Removing Duplicates in a CSV file

Tags: sorting, powershell, unique

first of all, I'm very new to Powershell, and I would like to thank all the participants of this site for helping me by providing answers across different fourms!  I've accomplished a lot in a short time because of this site!

Here is the issue, and I'll do my best to explain.  I have a CSV file to create student accounts.  Our Student management system produces a record each time a student enrolls, is altered, or exits a program.  If that student "trys out" a few different programs, they will have multiple records in the CSV file. So my goal is to Sort the CSV file by userID (the userID never changes) and by CurrentStatusDate (which is when the record was created). Using this command:

```
Import-CSV "C:\students.csv" | sort UserID,CurrentStatusDate
```

Sample of CSV records:

```
"UserID","AccountStatus","PersonID","PIN","FirstName","LastName","IDEXPIRY","Term","Role","Course","SectionName","locationDescription","Location","CurrentStatusDate"
"aboggs","Add","xxxxxxx","xxxxxxx","Ashley","Baggs","5/11/2013","xxxxxx","Student","Accounting Technology","xxxxxx","xxxxxx","xxxxxx","9/12/2011"
"aboutilier","Add","xxxxxxx","xxxxxxx","Amelia","Boutilier","5/3/2012","xxxxxx","Student","Adult Education","xxxxxx","xxxxxx","xxxxxx","11/15/2011"
"abowtle","Delete","xxxxxxx","xxxxxxx","Aleisha","Bowtle","7/31/2013","xxxxxx","Student","Business Administration","xxxxxx","xxxxxx","xxxxxx","2/1/2011"
"abowtle","Add","xxxxxxx","xxxxxxx","Aleisha","Bowtle","7/31/2012","xxxxxx","Student","General Studies","xxxxxx","xxxxxx","xxxxxx","9/9/2011"
"abradley","Delete","xxxxxxx","xxxxxxx","Anna","Bradley","10/25/2011","xxxxxx","Student","Adult Education","xxxxxx","xxxxxx","xxxxxx","11/17/2011"
"abridges","Delete","xxxxxxx","xxxxxxx","Ashley","Bridges","10/5/2011","xxxxxx","Student","Adult Education","xxxxxx","xxxxxx","xxxxxx","11/15/2011"
"abrown10165","Add","xxxxxxx","xxxxxxx","Adam","Brown","10/28/2011","xxxxxx","Student","Advanced Firefighting STCW VI/3","xxxxxx","xxxxxx","xxxxxx","10/24/2011"
"abrown10165","Add","xxxxxxx","xxxxxxx","Adam","Brown","12/16/2011","xxxxxx","Student","Simulated Electronic Navigation Level 1, Part B","xxxxxx","xxxxxx","xxxxxx","11/10/2011"
"abrown8081","Add","xxxxxxx","xxxxxxx","Alex","Brown","5/25/2013","xxxxxx","Student","Culinary Arts","xxxxxx","xxxxxx","xxxxxx","9/6/2011"
"abrown8950","Delete","xxxxxxx","xxxxxxx","Ashley","Brown","9/13/2012","xxxxxx","Student","Medical Support Services","xxxxxx","xxxxxx","xxxxxx","9/14/2011"
"acameron2637","Delete","xxxxxxx","xxxxxxx","Anne","Cameron","10/14/2011","xxxxxx","Student","Adult Education","xxxxxx","xxxxxx","xxxxxx","10/14/2011"
"acameron4368","Add","xxxxxxx","xxxxxxx","Amanda","Cameron","4/20/2013","xxxxxx","Student","Applied Degree in Culinary Operations","xxxxxx","xxxxxx","xxxxxx","10/12/2011"
"acampbell10266","Add","xxxxxxx","xxxxxxx","Amanda","Campbell","5/4/2012","xxxxxx","Student","Adult Education","xxxxxx","xxxxxx","xxxxxx","11/7/2011"
"acampbell6499","Delete","xxxxxxx","xxxxxxx","Aaron","Campbell","10/31/2012","xxxxxx","Student","Retail Business Management","xxxxxx","xxxxxx","xxxxxx","11/1/2011"
"acampbell6499","Add","xxxxxxx","xxxxxxx","Aaron","Campbell","12/13/2011","xxxxxx","Student","Complete the Accounting Cycle - Part II","xxxxxx","xxxxxx","xxxxxx","9/26/2011"
```

This should group all the userID's with the same records, then sort them by date created.  I then want to remove the duplicates and retain the last record created.  I'm familiar with the -Unique, but it doesn't apply to the command above as it will only remove records that have duplicate userID and CurrentStatusDates.

If been "Google-ing" and banging my head for 2 days... starting to think there is no "easy" answer, but my programming-fu is weak... Just looking for a "nudge" in the right direction.

Thanks!

Chris

Comment: If you could post sample input and show expected output, it would help .

Comment: Of course Andy, I'm sorry... I should have known to post some lines from the csv... I've updated my original post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Andy stated, it's a little hard given we don't have a sample of the CSV format. However I'm thinking that something like the below is what you're looking for:

```
Import-CSV "C:\students.csv" | Group-Object userid | foreach-object { $_.group | sort-object currentstatusdate | select -last 1}
```

Just as you describe - we group by ID, then sort by CurrentStatusDate, then select most-recent record. I'm not sure how CurrentStatusDate is formatted, so I don't know if a straight sort-object will be good enough.

Comment: Thank you riknik, I've updated my original post with a sample from the csv .. Love your code snipit, I will try it and let you know..

Comment: Worked Perfectly!! Not sure who is thanking you more... the dents in the wall, or the dents in my head!

Comment: As mjoliner mentions in his answer, beware how the dates are sorted. In above example, they are sorted alphabetically, not with any knowledge of how dates work. Since you're working with calendar dates and not date+time you may be able to get away with it, otherwise this solution will need some tweaking to modify the sort-object bit.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

- joining the fields together (http://www.johndcook.com/PowerShellCookbook.html#a19) on a seperator
- use unique
- split

Comment: Not sure if that would work in my case... if both fields were joined then there would be no duplicates anymore for the unique to process... but... I didn't know you could do that, so now I've learned something else for future challenges!  Thanks Chriseyre2000

Answer (score 0):

Not tested:

```
 $new_csv = @()
 Import-CSV "C:\students.csv" | sort UserID |
  foreach {
    if ($temp -eq $null){$temp = $_}
    if ($_.UserID -ne $temp.UserID){
       $new_csv += $temp
       $temp = $_
       }
elseif ([datetime]$_.CurrentStatusDate -gt [datetime]$temp.CurrentStatusDate){
   $temp = $_
   }
 } 
 $new_csv += $temp
 export-csv $new_csv c:\somedir\new_csv.csv -notype
```

When the first record comes through, $temp will get set to that record.  As each new record comes through, if it's for the same student ID, the timestamp gets checked agains the record in $temp.  If it's newer, that gets put into $temp.  When it sees the userID change, it writes $temp (which should now contian the newest record for the last user) to $new_csv.  Then it sets $temp to the current record, and starts over for the next userID.  Since it won't see a userid change for the last account, you have to pick that one up after the loop finishes, then export the csv.

Not sure exactly what format that timestamp is in, but I'm assuming it will parse correctly to [datetime].  But if it's coming from .csv it's going to be a string, and it seemed unlikely it would sort in datetime order on a string sort, so I didn't even bother.

Comment: Wow mjolinor, beautiful code!  Since I'm a newbie to this, I don't mind saying that I have no idea what it means/does... but I promise you that I'm going to find out... It's code like this that I learn alot from!  I'll test it the best I can and get back to you!

Comment: @mjolinor - "continue" doesn't do what you think in a foreach-object block.

Comment: Thanks. I missed that. It can do without it. See anything else wrong?

Comment: @ca269 I think you might find that part about date strings not sorting in datetime order of some consequence.

Comment: Yeah, you're right... but mjolinor's answer still answers my question.  I'm going to see if our source for the CSV can give us a system time instead, then apply the provided Code...  Thanks again

Comment: The other script will run, but I'd verify the results. It's relying on an alpha sort of a date string to sort in chronological order.  For that to work, your date string digits have to be in the order yyyy/mm/dd - high order to low order, with the months and days zero-filled to 2 digits.  Yours are not in that format or order.